# plupload does not seem to be uploading files in IE 9. It works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, plupload

In our project we are using plupload to upload a single excel file. This is working in all the browsers except IE9. On click of the upload link the file dialog box is displayed but nothing happens when tried to open the excel. Below is the code for reference and any help to solve this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
function initUploader(btnId, fileType, onSuccess) {

    if (typeof fileType == "undefined") fileType = "image";

    var arrFilters = new Array();
    var url = 'user/attachmentUpload';

    switch (fileType) {
        case "image": 
            arrFilters = [{title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"}]; 
            url = 'assets/imgupload';
            break;
        case "xls":
            arrFilters = [{title : "Spreadsheet files", extensions : "xls,xlsx"}]; 
            url = 'user/attachmentUpload';
            break;
        case "media":
            arrFilters = [{
                title : "Media files", 
                extensions : "mpeg4,mob,3gpp,avi,wmv,mp3,m4a,ogg,wav"
            }]; 
            break; 
        case "document":      
            arrFilters = [{
                title : "Text files", 
                extensions : "doc,docx"
            },{
                title : "PDF files", 
                extensions : "pdf"
            }]; 
            break; 
        default:      
            arrFilters = [
                {
                    title : "Image files", 
                    extensions : "jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
                },
                {
                    title : "Zip files", 
                    extensions : "zip"
                },
                {
                    title : "Media files", 
                    extensions : "mpeg4,mob,3gpp,avi,wmv,mp3,m4a,ogg,wav"
                },
                {
                    title : "Spreadsheet files", 
                    extensions : "xls,xlsx"
                },
                {
                    title : "Text files", 
                    extensions : "doc,docx"
                },
                {
                    title : "PDF files", 
                    extensions : "pdf"
                }
            ]; 
            break; 
    }

    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'gears,html5,html4,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
        browse_button : btnId,
        //container : 'container',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        url : url,
        flash_swf_url : 'assets/js/vendor/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url : 'assets/js/vendor/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap',
        multiple_queues : false,
        filters : arrFilters,
        resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90}
    });

    $('#'+btnId).change(function(){
        uploader.start();
    });    
    uploader.refresh();
    uploader.init();
    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
        Utility.showProcessingBar();
        uploader.start();
    });
    uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.code + ", Message: " + err.message + (err.file ? ", File: " + err.file.name : ""));
        up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
    });

    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
        var obj = eval('(' + response.response + ')');
        //alert('Files uploaded');
        if (typeof onSuccess == "function")
            onSuccess(obj.fileName);   
    });

}
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: "This is working in all the browsers except IE9." please specify in detail. Does it work in IE8 , IE 7 & IE10 ?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the library?

Comment: Any error in console ? Any visible demo ?

Answer (score 4):

For everyone who has the same problem as me:

I had the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container" style="display:none">
    <div>
        Logo:
    </div>
    <div style="clear"></div>

    <div id="uploader">
        <div id="runtime" class="right">
            No runtime was found !
        </div>
        <div>
            <a id="pickfiles" href="#">[Select files]</a>
            <a id="uploadfiles" href="#">[Upload files]</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class `container` was created as dialog:

```
$(function(){
    $(".container").dialog({modal:true, width:400});
});
```

As we know that the `div` is initially hidden because of `display: none` (of course, you can set up `autoOpen:false` as a new option in the dialog object), we can remove the style.

In IE8 (probably in earlier and later version) the uploader cannot be instantiated properly if the `div` is hidden. (Returns the above error)

In Chrome and Firefox (I did't test this issue in Opera), it works fine.

So, my advice is to avoid hidden blocks (even if you wish to create a modal dialog).

I removed the `display:none` style and `dialog` object from that `div` and now it works very good in IE8.

Why? I don't know why in IE, the instance of object is not created at the start-up of the page, though in Firefox and Chrome, the instance was created normally.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment ( had a small vocation ), but that's exactly what I ended up with. I removed the `display:none`, and afterwards put it in `$(document).ready(function(){});` to hide the fields. Now it works on IE8 & IE9 too. ( didn't test it on lower ones though, since I need only support from IE9+

Answer (score 1):

For max compatibility you should rearrange the plugins priority list.

```
 var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'gears,html5,html4,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
```

REPLACE THAT WITH

```
 var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'flash,html5,silverlight,browserplus,gears,html4',
```

Make sure the flash file exist and the path is relative to the location of your js file.

```
flash_swf_url : 'assets/js/vendor/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with this jquery.

You can try this out as I am working with this in ie7+ and all browser fro my file uploads.

Here is the file code I am newbie on how to upload js file at here.

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="javascript:void(0);" autocomplete="off">
                            <div class="vasplusfile_adds">
                                <label>Upload More</label>
                                <input type="hidden" name="myfile"  />
                                <div class="input customfile-container">
                                    <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="file" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="input" id="status" align="left" > </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>


<script>
  $(function() {
     $('#upload_file').live('change',function() { 
    $("#status").html('<div id="upload_now" class="btn">Click to Upload</div>');});
    $('#upload_now').live('click', function() { 
       $("#uploadForm").vPB({ beforeSubmit: function() { 
           $("#status").html('<div style="" align="center">Loading</div>');
            url: '',
            success: function(response) { // my response after file uploaded 
         }}).submit(); }); }); 
</script>
```

Example can be found from [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZceeE/9/).

Have a happy coding :)

live demo use working in ie7
http://vasplus.info/demos/upload_without_page_refresh/index.php

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You do not upload files here.  You post their content and indent by 4 spaces to get it to look like code.  For regular text, do not indent at all.  More tips can be found on the [Markdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) section.

Comment: I submitted a suggested edit which I believe does what you want. :)

Comment: thanks jeremy. you can use that $.event in change event of file controller.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.  You may find it helpful to edit the post with the changes I have made to see how I got it to look that way -- and then you can change it to what you are saying here.

Comment: this is strange.. you have a .success function checking if it was false ?

Comment: Updated in answer. Thanks Jeremy Miler for help :)

Comment: I don't think the issue is _how to upload_ but specifically with the [PlUpload plugin](http://www.plupload.com/) and IE9