# Plupload runtimes IE <10

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, plupload

I can't resolve a problem with plupload, jquery and ajax on IE < 10. On the others browsers, I have not a problem (firefox, chrome, IE10+).

When I run my form after having chosen, I have this error :

"Breaking on JScript runtime error" 
"SCRIPT5022: NOT_FOUND_ERR: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOMException 8"
"plupload.full.min.js, line 15 character 24347"

My code is as follow :
upload.js

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
browse_button: 'browse', // this can be an id of a DOM element or the DOM element itself                                                                                                                 
runtimes : 'html5,flash,html4',
url: '/test_carnac_plupload/upload.php',
container : 'container',
max_file_size : '1mb',
multipart : 'false',
multi_selection : 'false',
filters: [
    {title: "fasta", extensions : "fasta, fa"}
],
flash_swf_url : "/libs/Moxie.swf",
});


uploader.init();

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
  var file_info = '';
  plupload.each(files, function(file) {
    file_info = file.name + '(' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ')';
   });
  $("#name_file").text(file_info);
});

uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
   alert("Current runtime: " + params.runtime);
});

uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
   if(err.code=="-600"){
     alert("Your fasta file is too big, the size maximum is 1mb");
   }
   else if(err.code=="-601"){
     alert("The file accepted are the fasta with the extension : .fasta and .fa");
   }
   else{
     alert(Error+" : "+err.code + ": " + err.message);
   }
 });
```

form.php

```
<html><body>
<form id="formulaire" method="post">
 <div class="formulaire">
<table class="vide">
  <tr>
<td class="label">Enter a <b>name</b> for the sequences 
  <i>(optional) </i> : 
  <input type="text" name="seq_name" size="20" />
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="formulaire">
<table class="vide">
  <tr>
<td class="label"><b>Paste</b> your RNA sequences in FASTA
  format &nbsp;&nbsp;[<a href="#carnac/help.php#fasta">?</a>]
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>
  <textarea id="paste_seq" name="sequence" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>
  or
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="label"> 
  <div id="container">
     <table><tr>
     <td><b>upload</b> a file</td>
         <td><button id="browse">Parcourir...</button></td>
         <td><div id="name_file">None</div></td>
     </table>
  </div> 
</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
<td><input id="ex1" type="submit" name="example" value="Example" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="formulaire">
<table class="vide">
  <tr>
<td class="label">
  <input type="checkbox" name="GC" value="pourcentage GC" />
  Disable threshold correction according to GC%
  [<a href="#carnac/help.php#gccontent">?</a>]
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>


<div class="formulaire">
  <table class="vide">
  <tr>
 <td class="label"> 
  Enter your <b>E-mail</b> address <i>(optional)</i>: 
  <input type="text" name="email" size="20" />
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="center">
<input type="submit" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /> 
<input type="submit" id="run" name="button" value="Run CARNAC" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="request" /> 
</div>

<script src="/test_carnac_plupload/js/upload_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/test_carnac_plupload/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</form>

</body><html>
```

I hope someone can help me as I seek the solution for long time.

Thank you.

Alan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014586/plupload-does-not-seem-to-be-uploading-files-in-ie-9-it-works-in-other-browsers

Comment: I tried this solution but I have not the same problem because "container" is visible and it does not work on IE 9, 8, 7 and 6. I think is a problem with the html4 runtimes.